# Adding custom attribute to a class defined in asp.net inline code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-attributes, inline-code

I have an asp.net page that is already written with inline vb.net. All I really need to do is add a custom attribute to the class but it can't figure out where to add it.

```
     <%@ Page Language="vb" %>

    <script runat="server"> 

        Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

           ...

        End Sub
    </script>
```

In the code that checks for the attribute on the page object, I can see the page.GetType.fullName = "ASP.test_aspx" with the page filename as test.aspx.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking if you can add a field to this page that you've defined? Have tried just adding it within your <script runat="server"> tag as something like this: Private Foo as Integer?

Comment: No, I mean an actual custom attribute to add metadata to a class. You'll see them defined like this <myattribute()> Class MyClass ... End Class [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly as the class is autogenerated and I'm pretty sure that the compiler doesn't have provision for adding attributes.  Personally, I'd rewrite the page with a separate class file (I always prefer to do that anyway).  If that isn't an option, depending on the attribute and what is using it, you may be able to create a class that inherits from Page with the attribute on and inherit from in the the @Page directive